# Phonegap app clear pushnotifications doesn't work

Tags: javascript, cordova, notifications

My app does receive push notifications from GCM.
There is then in my iOS device a number displayed on the icon equal to the amount or received notifications.

I'd like to clear this when opening the app. 
According to the documentation i have to use these lines of code:

```
push.clearAllNotifications(function() {
   alert("1");
}, function() {
   alert("2");
});
```

However, all code after this is not working and neither does one of the two alerts show. And ofcourse the number is still being displayed on the icon.
Any tips or alternatives?

EDIT:
My current code:

```
function startPush() {

            var push = PushNotification.init({
                android: {
                    senderID: "xxxx",
                    vibrate: true
                },
                ios: {
                    senderID: "951044503850",
                    gcmSandbox: false,
                    alert: "true",
                    badge: true,
                    sound: 'false',
                    clearBadge: "true"
                }
            });

            push.on('registration', function(data) {
                var regID = data.registrationId;
               alert(regID);
                //this works


            });
            push.clearAllNotifications(function() {
               alert("1");
               //does not fire
            }, function() {
               alert("2");
               // does not fire
            });
```

}

I do receive a registrationId so that part does work. HOwever the alert(1) or alert(2) do not fire so this part is not functional.
BTW for bonus points ;), my phone doesn't vibrate on push notification either

Comment: have you init the push variable?

Comment: @jcesarmobile Well i edited my "question" and now you can see what i did. The fact that i do get a valid registrationId to, and it works, i can send push notifications i think i can state that the push variable has been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative Solution**

Add [Cordova Badge Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge) and set badge 0(zero) on app init

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    cordova.plugins.notification.badge.set(0);
}, false);
```

Or wherever you want to hide icon's badges

Comment: Thanks for this alternative, another workaround is to add the clearBadge index in the initialisation.

Comment: Yes, it is more better than adding new plugin to the application. If you completed your requirements with that than just an upvote to my answer ;)

Comment: I'm still wondering why my original code is not working because it is the default given function by the plugin description. It Should work but it doesn't...

Comment: As we cannot able to set or get alert on foreground push notification, same way may be this will also not fire any alert on execution, if you want to check if this is working or not you can add `badge plugin` and set any static badge into success and failure and if this is working you will get that static number on the app icon